# Creating a ribbon custom button when inserting content to Sharepoing 2010

Tags: sharepoint, plugins, sharepoint-2010, ribbon, ribbon-control

I want to create a button to popup a window and display a list that it's being requested to an external source. Then the user would click on one of the items to insert and iframe on the body of the post.

For this I think best way is to create a ribbon custom button right? How can I make it only appear when inserting content such as posts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a custom action in your project. It's a small xml file that gets installed in the farm and dislays what ever you want. Check [How to add a ribbon item using CustomAction in sharepoint 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13011196/how-to-add-a-ribbon-item-using-customaction-in-sharepoint-2010) for a sample and here for extended information on all the possibilities you have http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb802730.aspx