# Add Date Control in SharePoint Ribbon menu

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ribbon

Is it Possible to add a date control in SharePoint Ribbon controls.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to add a custom action the dislays a modal window with a calendar. You will need to

1. Create a custom page or layout with the calendar
2. Create a custom ribbon action that invokes a modaldialog

Check here for more information [Creating a ribbon custom button when inserting content to Sharepoing 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406160/creating-a-ribbon-custom-button-when-inserting-content-to-sharepoing-2010/18416545#18416545)